# Overridding GWT RequestTransport

Tags: json, gwt

I want to create a GWT client application that retrieves data using RequestFactory. However, I want this client application to hit a JSON webservice backend.

If this is possible at all, it should have something to do with overriding DefaultRequestTransport and setting a new request URL for the data. However, from this point on, the weeds get pretty thick, and the docs are rather thin.

Anyone have any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding `RequestFactory` to work with JSON will be very hard, if at all possible.

Why not use the GWT [default support for JSON](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSON.html)?

Comment: The same point was made to me elsewhere. I'm looking at using a combination of RequestBuilder and AutoBeans at this point.